# Execution failed for task ':paytm_allinone_react-native:compileDebugKotlin'. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, payment-gateway, paytm

## **Paytm gateway integration in react native**

I'm using All-in-One SDK Integration for React Native platform

I also tried to upgrade the kotlin version

```
kotlinVersion = "1.4.10"
```

and

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `kotline version`:- `1.5.10` in

project/node_modules/paytm_allinone_react-native/android/gradle.properties

```
ArnPaytmAllinone_kotlinVersion=1.5.10
```

after clear the build and uninstall the project then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

changed kotlin version to `kotlinVersion = "1.5.31"` in `android/build.gradle`

**Note** : If this error comes back, Uninstall app from emulator and build again or Delete this emulator and create new one and try.

Hope it will work!